# Copy control in abstract classes

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I have an abstract class and two concrete subclasses (Store), both with a pointer to another concrete subclass which is derived from an abstract class (Factory). Below is the code for the Store. I wanted to prevent memory leaks, so I started to write the copy control. I can't instantiate a new Factory however, because I don't know upfront what type it will be. What is a good practice to circumvent this? I could write the copy control in the concrete Stores, but then I have duplicate code.
I also tried to work with smart pointers instead, but there I find another difficulty. The snippet `myFactory = std::make_shared<AbstractFactory>(ConcreteFactoryA());` apparently creates an AbstractFactory first, and then fills it with a ConcreteFactoryA. However, as the name suggests, AbstractFactory cannot be instantiated, as the compiler is telling me. Can you use shared_ptrs with abstract classes?

Code with plain pointers:

```
#pragma once
#include "AbstractFactory.h"

class AbstractStore
{
public:
    // Copy control
    AbstractStore(const AbstractStore& orig) : myFactory(new AbstractFactory(orig.myFactory)) {}
    AbstractStore& operator=(const AbstractStore& orig) { return *this; } // TODO
    ~AbstractStore(void) {}
protected:
    // Constructor
    AbstractStore(void) {}
    // Data members
    AbstractFactory* myFactory;
};

class ConcreteStoreA : public AbstractStore
{
public:
    ConcreteStoreA(void) { myFactory = new ConcreteFactoryA; }
    ~ConcreteStoreA(void) {}
};

class ConcreteStoreB : public AbstractStore
{
public:
    ConcreteStoreB(void) { myFactory = new ConcreteFactoryB; }
    ~ConcreteStoreB(void) {}
};
```

Code with smart pointers:

```
#pragma once
#include "AbstractFactory.h"
#include <memory>

class AbstractStore
{
public:
    // Copy control
    AbstractStore(const AbstractStore& orig) : myFactory(orig.myFactory) {}
    AbstractStore& operator=(const AbstractStore& orig) { myFactory = orig.myFactory; return *this; }
    ~AbstractStore(void) {}
protected:
    // Constructor
    AbstractStore(void) {}
    // Data members
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractFactory> myFactory;
};

class ConcreteStoreA : public AbstractStore
{
public:
    ConcreteStoreA(void) { myFactory = std::make_shared<AbstractFactory>(ConcreteFactoryA()); }
    ~ConcreteStoreA(void) {}
};

class ConcreteStoreB : public AbstractStore
{
public:
    ConcreteStoreB(void) { myFactory = std::make_shared<AbstractFactory>(ConcreteFactoryB()); }
    ~ConcreteStoreB(void) {}
};
```

Comment: Side note: All your destructors in abstract classes probably need to be declared `virtual`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `make_shared` correctly. Use:

```
std::make_shared<ConcreteFactory>();
```

You call it without any arguments here. `make_shared` is not accepting a constructed object but the arguments that are forwarded to it's constructor. In your case you would be forwarding to the copy constructor, which works poorly with abstract hierarchies. If you want copyable objects in hierarchies, use `clone` member functions with covariant return types.

This will return a `shared_ptr<ConcreteFactory>` which will be converted to `shared_ptr<AbstractFactory>` in the assignment (see (9) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). Also, use constructor initializer lists and virtual destructors.

Comment: I changed the constructors of the concrete Stores to `ConcreteStoreA(void) : AbstractStore( std::make_shared<ConcreteFactoryA>(ConcreteFactoryA()) ) { }` and now it works. Is this what you meant? Because I still have an argument list here.

Comment: EDIT: I didn't understand your sentence with the argument list, but now I do. I removed the argument. I still don't understand your last sentence in the first paragraph though. What are covariant return types?

Comment: @physicalattraction A virtual function that is overridden in a derived class can change the return type to a `narrower` type. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor

Answer (score 0):

You probably want one of these two things to make your smart pointer approach work:

1. Make `ConcreteFactoryA` and `ConcreteFactoryB` return a `std::shared_ptr<AbstractFactory>` or `std::unique_ptr<AbstractFactory>`. Simply assign, or better yet, initialize, in your "Store" classes
2. Initialize your `shared_ptr<>`s from raw pointers using `std::shared_ptr<>::reset` or the constructor

You would normally only use `std::make_shared<>` with smart pointers where you use `new` with raw pointers. In your case, you are simply assigning the pointer, so you shouldn't use it.